# What are the methods an application can use to auto-start (in kubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: kubuntu, autostart, korganizer

I know of System Settings/Startup and Shutdown, and I've found ~/.config/autostart and ~/.config/autostart-scripts. But what other methods can an application employ to auto-start on boot/login?

This question is prompted by accidentally running KOrganizer which then auto-started every time I logged in. I solved this somewhat brutally by removing KOrganizer but it has left me wondering what might be auto-starting in the background without my knowledge, so I would like to be able to check.

Comment: Did you look at *Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Desktop Session > On Login*?  Could it be that you have something like "Restore previous session" enabled?

Comment: There is also `cron` that you set up with `crontab`. See `info crontab`. You can find good tutorials about `crontab` via the internet. This way you can run programs that need no desktop (for example programs that write to files or send output to the loudspeakers) and not only your own user tasks but also system tasks (backups, update & upgrade of program packages, even shutdown at a certain time).